# SQL Server 2008 R2: Reduce multiple condtions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a multiple parameters to check for the condition. As per the condition I am preparing the where clause.

Here is the SQL Fiddle of all conditions which I have prepared.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/5964)

Can I reduce the code for same conditions?

Comment: might have better luck on code review, in addition to sql fiddle code should be posted in the body of the question, why do you have the `IF @Name <> ''` condition check in every if block when the entirety is wrapped in a check of the same thing?  Also your fiddle doesn't compile

Comment: Your fiddle have sintaxis error. And even when fiddle are very usefull you should always try to include your code here.  Because sometime the fiddle is down and viewer wont be able to see your code. Maybe not all but at least the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full source:

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(max) = 'John'
DECLARE @NameCondition VARCHAR(10) = 'Exact'
DECLARE @Phonetic INT = 1
DECLARE @WhereCondition VARCHAR(MAX) = 'WHERE '

IF @Name <> ''
BEGIN
    IF @Phonetic = 0
    BEGIN
        IF (LEN(@Name) - LEN(REPLACE(@Name,',','')) + 1) = 1
        BEGIN
            IF @NameCondition = 'Exact'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' FirstName = '''+@Name+'''';
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'Containing'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' FirstName LIKE ''%'+@Name+'%''  AND';
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'Start with'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' FirstName LIKE '''+@Name+'%''  AND';
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'End with'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' FirstName LIKE ''%'+@Name+'''  OR';
        END
        ELSE IF (LEN(@Name) - LEN(REPLACE(@Name,',','')) + 1) > 1
        BEGIN
            IF @NameCondition = 'Exact'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' FirstName IN('''+REPLACE(@Name,',',''',''')+''')  AND';
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'Containing'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' FirstName LIKE '''+REPLACE(@Name,',','%'' OR FirstName LIKE ''')+'%''  AND';
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'Start with'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' FirstName LIKE '''+REPLACE(@Name,',','%'' OR FirstName LIKE ''')+'%''  AND';
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'End with'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' FirstName LIKE ''%'+REPLACE(@Name,',',''' OR FirstName LIKE ''%')+'''  AND';
        END
    END
    ELSE IF @Phonetic = 1
    BEGIN
        IF (LEN(@Name) - LEN(REPLACE(@Name,',','')) + 1) = 1
        BEGIN
            IF @NameCondition = 'Exact'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' SOUNDEX(FirstName) = SOUNDEX('''+@Name+''')  AND';
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'Containing'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' SOUNDEX(FirstName) LIKE SOUNDEX(''%'+@Name+'%'')  OR';
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'Start with'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' SOUNDEX(FirstName) LIKE SOUNDEX('''+@Name+'%'')  AND';
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'End with'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' SOUNDEX(FirstName) LIKE SOUNDEX(''%'+@Name+''')  AND';
        END
        ELSE IF (LEN(@Name) - LEN(REPLACE(@Name,',','')) + 1) > 1
        BEGIN
            IF @NameCondition = 'Exact'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' SOUNDEX(FirstName) IN (SOUNDEX('''+REPLACE(@Name,',',''') , SOUNDEX(''')+'''))  AND';
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'Containing'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' SOUNDEX(FirstName) LIKE (SOUNDEX(''%'+REPLACE(@Name,',','%'') , SOUNDEX(''%')+'%''))  AND';
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'Start with'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' SOUNDEX(FirstName) LIKE (SOUNDEX('''+REPLACE(@Name,',','%'') , SOUNDEX(''')+'%''))  AND';
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'End with'
                SET @WhereCondition += ' SOUNDEX(FirstName) LIKE (SOUNDEX(''%'+REPLACE(@Name,',',''') , SOUNDEX(''%')+'''))  AND';
        END
    END
END


PRINT(@WhereCondition);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that every case is different so I think you could only compress/optimize code using a similar syntax:

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(max) = 'John'
DECLARE @NameCondition VARCHAR(10) = 'Exact'
DECLARE @Phonetic INT = 1
DECLARE @WhereCondition VARCHAR(MAX) = 'WHERE '

IF @Name <> ''
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Test AS INTEGER
    SELECT @Test = LEN(@Name) - LEN(REPLACE(@Name,',','')) + 1

    IF @Phonetic = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @Test = 1
        BEGIN
            IF @NameCondition = 'Exact' SET @WhereCondition += ' FirstName = '''+@Name+''''
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'Containing' SET @WhereCondition += ' FirstName LIKE ''%'+@Name+'%''  AND'
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'Start with' SET @WhereCondition += ' FirstName LIKE '''+@Name+'%''  AND'
            ELSE IF @NameCondition = 'End with' SET @WhereCondition += ' FirstName LIKE ''%'+@Name+'''  OR'
        END
        ELSE IF @Test > 1
        BEGIN
            -- every case of @NameCondition with @Phonetic = 0 and @Test > 1
        END
    END
    ELSE IF @Phonetic = 1
    BEGIN
        IF @Test = 1
        BEGIN
            -- every case of @NameCondition with @Phonetic = 1 and @Test = 1 
        END
        ELSE IF @Test > 1
        BEGIN
            -- every case of @NameCondition with @Phonetic = 1 and @Test > 1 
        END
    END

END
```